# Is there a way to get `cabal` to detect changes to non-Haskell source files?

Tags: haskell, cabal, template-haskell

I'm using template haskell to include content from non-Haskell files in some of my code, and this content is then parsed and used. The problem that I have with using `cabal` as a build tool for this is that it doesn't detect when these files changes and so I find myself using `cabal clean; cabal build` which forces the *whole* project to be rebuilt (including some dependencies) which is slower than it could otherwise be.

Answer (score 3):

Call [`Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.addDependentFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.8.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:addDependentFile), then [wait for this cabal issue to get fixed](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4746).

As a workaround, you can add a comment to some relevant Haskell source file(s) to get them to rebuild (and re-execute their TH). Don't forget to delete it again next build and certainly before you check your source in!

Comment: I think this Cabal issue may actually be fixed.  I spotted the same issue after you first posted your answer, but when I tested the Gist, I couldn't reproduce the issue.  Modifying `fileinput` resulted in Cabal correctly rebuilding `Main.hs`.